# How to Dockerize react app with huge data

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a React App which needs to be Dockerized. In public folder I have 4GB of .png images. Just wondering if it is a good idea to dockerize the entire app or is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Since you've tagged AWS into this, I'd say those images should be served from S3, not a public folder in the app.

Comment: You should pretty much never bundle 4GB of images, especially in a web React application- like @AKX said, S3 should be your go-to solution here

Comment: My bad, I forgot to remove AWS tag. I cant use S3. Since application will be running in intranet (which won't have internet connection).

Comment: One thing to consider is if the app and the images are coupled. When you change the app, do you also change the images? If the images rarely change, then decoupling the images and the app can be a good idea. If they change together, then bundling them makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dockerize the app and put the folder with the images outside and just volume it in. Saving both time on build and space in the container.

`docker run --name containername -v ~/Folder-outside:/images -d imagename:latest`

Comment: Can you talk more about when this approach would and would not be appropriate?  If you're deploying this setup, how do the images get on to the production system, if they're not contained in the Docker image?

Comment: I would use this for a case like this or like on our local dev environments we have oracle12c in a container where the database tables are located in a volume. We create our tablespaces in this volume to not bloat down the container and to get around the standard max size of 10GB (i think this still is the case?).

well thats dependent on where the images are coming from but if you already have them, i would ,like the comments above store them in a particular storage or make a pipe to upload them to the production system.